# doFinal method of cipher object returning java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, encryption

```
public class SymmetricCipherTest {
    private static final String DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES";
    public final String ENCODE_INDICATOR_START = "ENC(";
    public final String ENCODE_INDICATOR_END = ")";
    public final String APP_ENCRYPTION_KEY_FILE = "application/.encryption.key";
    public static final int INTERATION = 15;
    private static final byte[] SALT = { (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xee,
            (byte) 0x99 };

//  private static SymmetricCipherTest instance = initApplicaitonKey();
    private static Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    private static Cipher encrypter;
    private static Cipher decrypter;
//  private final Base64 base64 = new Base64();

    private static final int KEYLENGTH = 256;
    public final String ERROR_KEY_GENERATION = "Encryption key generation failed. Please verify the logs.";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        String applicationKey="abcdefghijklmnopqrstu";
        String password="HellowWorld";
        try{
            SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
            PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(applicationKey.toCharArray());
            SecretKey key = kf.generateSecret(keySpec);
            Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance(DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);

            PBEParameterSpec params = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, INTERATION);
            ciph.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, params);
            encrypter=ciph;
            String encriptedString=new String(base64.encode(encrypter.doFinal(password.getBytes())));
            System.out.println(encriptedString);

            Cipher ciph1 = Cipher.getInstance(DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
            ciph1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, params);
            decrypter=ciph;
            String decryiptedString=new String(base64.decode(decrypter.doFinal(encriptedString.getBytes())));
            System.out.println(decryiptedString);

        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            System.out.println("No such algorithm");
        }

    }
}
```

Is my class I want to run. But when i Run This I am getting Out put exception as bellow.

```
EEb9pXx45M1WV16D4b9EmA==
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -64
    at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.isBase64(Base64.java:137)
    at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.discardNonBase64(Base64.java:478)
    at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:374)
    at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decode(Base64.java:220)
    at com.vxl.appanalytix.webapp.listener.SymmetricCipherTest.main(SymmetricCipherTest.java:54)
```

the line 54 in SymmetricCipherTest is "String decryiptedString=new String(base64.decode(decrypter.doFinal(encriptedString.getBytes())));". I am not getting Why i am getting this exception as i am very new with this topic.

UPDATE:

```
public class SymmetricCipherTest {
    private static final String DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES";
    public final String ENCODE_INDICATOR_START = "ENC(";
    public final String ENCODE_INDICATOR_END = ")";
    public final String APP_ENCRYPTION_KEY_FILE = "application/.encryption.key";
    public static final int INTERATION = 15;
    private static final byte[] SALT = { (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xee,
            (byte) 0x99 };

//  private static SymmetricCipherTest instance = initApplicaitonKey();
    private static Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    private static Cipher encrypter;
    private static Cipher decrypter;
//  private final Base64 base64 = new Base64();

    public final String ERROR_KEY_GENERATION = "Encryption key generation failed. Please verify the logs.";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, DecoderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String applicationKey="abcdefghijklmnopqrstu";
        String password="HellowWorld";
            encrypter=getCipherObject(applicationKey);
            String encriptedString=new String(base64.encode(encrypter.doFinal(password.getBytes())));
            System.out.println(encriptedString);

            decrypter=getCipherObject(applicationKey);
             String decryiptedString=new String(decrypter.doFinal(base64.decode(encriptedString.getBytes())));
            System.out.println(decryiptedString);

    }

    public static Cipher getCipherObject(String applicationKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException{
        SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(applicationKey.toCharArray());
        SecretKey key = kf.generateSecret(keySpec);
        Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance(DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);

        PBEParameterSpec params = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, INTERATION);
        ciph.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, params);
        return ciph;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You base64 encode after you encrypted with:

```
String encriptedString=new String(base64.encode(encrypter.doFinal(password.getBytes())));
```

so you need do base64 decode before you decrypt .. currently you try to decrypt the base64 encoded string. Try something like:

```
  String decryiptedString=new String(decrypter.doFinal(base64.decode(encriptedString.getBytes()));
```

Also, the line

```
decrypter=ciph;
```

needs to be

```
decrypter=ciph1;
```

Otherwise it's encrypted twice instead of encrypt + decrypt.

Comment: As per your suggestion i changed my code to "Cipher ciph1 = Cipher.getInstance(DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
   ciph1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, params);
   decrypter=ciph;
   byte[] decryiptedBytes= base64.decode(encriptedString.getBytes());
   String decripted=new String(decrypter.doFinal(decryiptedBytes));
   System.out.println(decripted);" . Now My outPut is "EEb9pXx45M1WV16D4b9EmA==
�x�|�o)";*:�0C�χ" without any exception. but I am to get exact decoded value

Comment: You do a decrypter=ciph;  this ought to be decrypter=ciph1;   otherwhise you encrypt it twise.

Comment: I updated the code as above but still get the same wrong answer. Please try with running my code. The output still i am getting is "EEb9pXx45M1WV16D4b9EmA==
�x�|�o)";*:�0C�χ
"

Comment: With above two changes i get: EEb9pXx45M1WV16D4b9EmA==
HellowWorld